# Custom Postgres Update Function

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which contains multiple rows for a user, holding their station_ids. When a station ID is changed from the front end via drop down button, I want to update the station ID in the table. I only want there to ever be one TRUE value for "is_default_station", but a user can have multiple FALSE values.  I am using postgres 9.5, and the PG drive for NodeJS.

My table looks like this:

```
  station_id     | station_name                |        user_id          |   is_default_station
-----------------+---------------------------- +-------------------------+--------------------------
    1            |  station 1                  |     1                   |          TRUE
    2            |  station 2                  |     1                   |          FALSE
    3            |  station 3                  |     1                   |          FALSE
    4            |  station 4                  |     2                   |          FALSE 
    5            |  station 5                  |     2                   |          FALSE 
    6            |  station 6                  |     2                   |          TRUE
```

Here is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UPDATE_All_STATIONS_FUNC (
userId INTEGER,
stationId INTEGER
)
RETURNS RECORD AS $$
DECLARE
  ret RECORD;
BEGIN
--Find all the user stations associated to a user, and set them to false. Then, update one to TRUE
UPDATE user_stations SET (is_default_station) = (FALSE) WHERE station_id = ALL (SELECT station_id FROM user_stations WHERE user_id =$1 AND is_default_station = TRUE);
UPDATE user_stations SET (is_default_station) = (TRUE) WHERE station_id =$2 AND user_id = $1 RETURNING user_id, station_id INTO ret;
RETURN ret;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am accessing the function like so:

```
SELECT user_id, station_id FROM update_all_stations_func($1, $2) AS (user_id INTEGER, station_id INTEGER)
```

The function is not updating anything on the DB, and returning null values for user_id and station_id like so `rows: [ { user_id: null, dashboard_id: null } ]`.

I am guessing that the initial update query with the nested SELECT is not finding anything *inside the function*, but if I use the first query alone to update, I find results and it updates as expected. What am I missing?

Comment: What is supposed to change from your function? What arguments are you providing? If you run it like `select update_all_stations_func(user_id, station_id) from user_stations` then the result is arbitrary.

Comment: Input = userId, stationId. Change = first, set all `is_default_station` fields to false based on userId passed in via input , then update the `is_default_station` value to true for the stationId passed in via input. Output = return the userId and the newly updated stationId, returning into an object format.

Comment: Edit your question. Provide exemplar call to the function and expected output.

Comment: I have provided the function call already. An example is irrelevant, as the numbers just get passed into the $$ variables in the function. Expected output is also shown, but expecting numbers instead of null.

Comment: Nope, there is no expected output for a given call. You don't include the MVCE. Try to call the function with what you've provided - it will have an error. Since you don't want me to help you, sure, just keep on waiting ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified the first update statement, and the following works as expected:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UPDATE_All_STATIONS_FUNC (
userId INTEGER,
stationId INTEGER
)
RETURNS RECORD AS $$
DECLARE
  ret RECORD;
BEGIN
--Find all the user stations associated to a user, and set them to false. Then, update one to TRUE
UPDATE user_stations SET (is_default_station) = (FALSE) WHERE user_id = $1 AND station_id <> $2;
UPDATE user_stations SET (is_default_station) = (TRUE) WHERE user_id = $1 AND station_id = $2 RETURNING user_id, station_id INTO ret;
RETURN ret;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```